# How to generate a Table of Contents “TOC” from merged file.TOC should be heading of each pages

Tags: itext

How to generate a Table of Contents “TOC”  from merged file.TOC should be heading of each pages.i have seen many examples, all TOC example worked on page number basis.I am using text pdf 5.5.11.

[image]

Comment: In which form do you have the information to build a TOC from?

Comment: You have seen many examples, but what have you tried? what was the result? and what was different from what you expected? What do you mean when you write *"TOC should be heading of each pages"*? TOC is the abbreviation of "Table Of Contents". Are you saying you want the TOC to be repeated as the heading of every page? Can you elaborate on that, because I don't understand why one would want that.

Comment: i have tried.TOC worked on page number basis.my expectation is TOC like "section 5.1.1 pages" when i click this TOC will navigate to a page having this heading

Comment: Am trying to create TOC from merged pdf files

Answer (score 2):

I would try following workflow:

1. Extract the text where you expect the header to be
2. Store (List of String) all headers and their corresponding pages
3. Loop over the list, and flatten it (eg [TitleA, TitleA, TitleB, ..] should become [TitleA, TitleB])
4. Now you have information on when every header appears for the first time
5. Use this information to build a TOC

If your document is tagged, this can be done in a way that will work more often (considering that using the approximate position of headers and simply extracting text there is a bit of a heuristic approach)